# Augmented Reality Mask using Facial Recognition on Xbox Kinect with Kinect for Windows SDK

Tags: image-processing, kinect, face-recognition, 3ds

I am using an XBox Kinect with the Kinect for Windows SDK.  I want to make an application that will augment a 3D mask (a 3D model of a mask made in 3DS Max) onto the face of anyone using the application.  The application will be used in an exhibit locally.  I have not tried much because I don't know where to start.  So what I want to know is, is it currently possible to augment a 3DS Max model onto a live video stream using the facial recognition and skeletal tracking features in the newest Kinect for Windows SDK, and if so, how/where should I start trying to do/implement this?  Any point in the right direction would be great.  Thank you!  PS And yes, I have read the UI guidelines and the facial documentation.  My problem is one of not knowing where to start programming, not one of not understanding the fundamental concepts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serious about getting into developing for the Kinect I would recommend getting this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Kinect-Windows-Software-Development/dp/0735666814](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735666814)

This goes through developing with the Kinect for Windows SDK from the ground up.  There is a face tracking and an augmented reality example so I'm pretty sure you will be able to achieve your goal quite easily.

All the code from the book is here:
http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/

---

Alternatively, there is an example here which pretty much is what you want to achieve:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213034/Kinect-Getting-Started-Become-The-Incredible-Hulk

It is developed using the Beta version of the SDK, but the same priciples apply.

---

You can also check out the quick start videos here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart

---

In summary, based on my own experience, I would spend some time going through the beginner examples either in the vides or the book (I found the book very good) just to get familiar with how to setup a simple Kinect project and how the different parts of the SDK work.

When you have developed some throwaway apps with the Kinect, I would then try tackling your project (although, the Incredible Hulk project above should get you most the way there!)

Best of luck with your project

Comment: I ended up using Zigfu, which worked well.  I used a sample avatar project, put the avatar in front of a video pane from another Zigfu sample, made the avatar's body invisible with a clear texture, and made the mask a child of the head on the avatar.  Hope this helps future mask-avatar programmers!